# MS SQL : The best way to delete rows from a ginormous table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, database-optimization

I have a very large table [X], which has 170 million rows, and we need to archive data to keep only used records in [X]. We are doing this to keep our system fast as it is slowing down. We are only using a small amount of rows from the whole table (speaking of less then 10%), so we can afford to archive a lot of data into for example Archive.[X].

The problem is that when we try to delete records, it takes a lot of time. Now we have run the following checks for troubleshooting to see any possibilities why it takes so long
1) The table is indexed
2) No un-indexed foreign keys
3) No triggers doing extra work in the background on delete

Have any of you ever encountered a similar scenario? What is the best procedure to follow when doing something similar? And are there any tools out there that can help?

I appreciate your help!

Comment: Have you tried deleting in increments with limits?

Comment: Is the transaction log on its own drive? Is it of sufficient size or is it spending a lot of time auto growing? Do you have to worry about blocking concurrent queries? Have you considered inserting the 10% to keep into a new table and then renaming rather than deleting and reinserting the 90%

Comment: Show us your delete statement and we might be able to diagnose it?

Comment: Yes, that is how I am proceeding, and it still takes forever.

Comment: If you are deleting 90 percent of the table I would recommend disabling foreign keys during the delete and disabling all indexes other than the one you are doing the look up on for the delete.

Comment: The transaction log is on a different drive, and yes it is rapidly auto growing not only because of this table, but of others. But we have parts of our system slowing down particularly because of this table [X], so it is our main concern. Blocking concurrent queries is something which we do not wish to do, as we have records inserted per second into table [X]. So if we block, we are stopping customer activity. Let's just say it's something out of the question now. The same reason stops us from moving just the 10%, as we need that table to be continuously active.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Options

- Why not take the 10% into a new table?
- Batch delete/insert *not* in a transaction (see below)
- Partition table (aka let the engine deal with it)

To populate an archive table

```
SELECT 'starting' -- sets @@ROWCOUNT
WHILE @@ROWCOUNT <> 0
BEGIN
    DELETE TOP (50000) dbo.Mytable
    OUTPUT DELETED.* INTO ArchiveTable 
    WHERE SomeCol < <Afilter>

    -- maybe CHECKPOINT

    WAIT FOR DELAY ...
END
```

Comment: So you are suggesting that I delete batches, until a criteria is met? Criteria being for example, a date range?

Comment: Here, "afilter" is a filter for "rows older than 6 months", for example. The criteria for "archive" data is up to you

Answer (score 2):

You should go for partitioning your database/table.

Comment: I agree with Kangkan - create 2 partitions -> used and unused data. Then the delete means that you switch the unused partition to a different table and drop the table.